# Create object from array of keys and values

Tags: arrays, json, object, transpose, jq

I've been banging my head against the wall for several hours on this and just can't seem to find a way to do this. I have an array of keys and an array of values, how can I generate an object? Input:

```
[["key1", "key2"], ["val1", "val2"]]
```

Output:

```
{"key1": "val1", "key2": "val2"}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Resolved this on [github](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/675):

```
.[0] as $keys |
.[1] as $values |
reduce range(0; $keys|length) as $i  ( {}; . + { ($keys[$i]): $values[$i] })
```

Answer (score 3):

The current version of jq has a `transpose` filter that can be used to pair up the keys and values.  You could use it to build out the result object rather easily.

```
transpose | reduce .[] as $pair ({}; .[$pair[0]] = $pair[1])
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff, I'm not sure that quite works though. I played around with it and the first portion seems to generate every key/val combination, but then the from_entries seems to override the right key/val pair with the wrong one. This is what I'm getting: `{
  "key1": "val2",
  "key2": "val2"
}`

Comment: Ah dang it, I knew that cross products might be an issue. When I checked it I thought it was fine. It's too bad there isn't a builtin `zip` filter. Then it would be trivial.

Comment: There is no need to use from_entries.  That is: transpose | map({ (.[0]): .[1] }) | add

Answer (score 2):

Just to be clear:

(0) Abdullah Jibaly's solution is simple, direct, efficient and generic, and should work in all versions of jq;

(1) transpose/0 is a builtin in jq 1.5 and has been available in pre-releases since Oct 2014;

(2) using transpose/0 (or zip/0 as defined above), an even shorter but still simple, fast, and generic solution to the problem is:

```
transpose | map( {(.[0]): .[1]} ) | add
```

Example:

```
$ jq 'transpose | map( {(.[0]): .[1]} ) | add'
```

Input:

```
[["k1","k2","k3"], [1,2,3] ]
```

Output:

```
{
  "k1": 1,
  "k2": 2,
  "k3": 3
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Scratch this, it doesn't actually work for any array greater than size 2.

`[map(.[0]) , map(.[1])] | map({(.[0]):.[1]}) | add`

Welp, I thought this would be easy, having a little prolog experience... oh man. I ended up banging my head against a wall too. Don't think I'll ever use jq ever again.

Comment: Thanks for the effort! I actually found the answer (see updated Q).

Comment: It's actually not too bad if we had some of the more typical functional methods such as `zip` built in. Fortunately it's not too bad implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which uses **reduce** with a state object holding an iteration index and a result object.  It iterates over the keys in `.[0]` setting corresponding values in the result from `.[1]`

```
  .[1] as $v
| reduce .[0][] as $k (
   {idx:0, result:{}}; .result[$k] = $v[.idx] | .idx += 1
  )
| .result
```