# Turn array of keys and array of values into object

Tags: arrays, json, jq

I have, for complicated reasons involving a trip from an Apple plist through `xml2json`, a number of JSON files with data in this form:

```
{ 
  "key": [ "key1", "key2", "key3" ],
  "string": [ "value1", "value2", "value3" ]
}
```

And I would like to convert that to a normal JSON object:

```
{ 
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
  "key3": "value3"     
}
```

After some head-banging, I came up with this `jq` program to do the trick:

```
jq '. as $d|[range(.key|length)|{"key":$d.key[.],"value":$d.string[.]}]|from_entries'
```

That works, but it seems a little convoluted. I was wondering if there were a cleaner solution?

This is indeed similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28103489), but the difference is that this is an object with named key and value elements instead just an array containing the two arrays directly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create object from array of keys and values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28103489/create-object-from-array-of-keys-and-values)

Comment: The linked question has the same idea, but in your case, you have an object of keys and values, rather than an array of keys and values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The script you provide is already pretty good! This variation of your script saves the index into the variable instead of the input object, which feels more natural to read for me. It then creates an array of one key objects and adds them together.

```
jq '[range(.key | length) as $i | {(.key[$i]): .string[$i]}] | add'
```

When I first looked at this issue, I though that a `zip` builtin would improve the situation. Then I remembered: there is already a `zip` builtin! It's just called `transpose`. Using it, you can create a script such as this:

```
jq '[.key, .string] | transpose | map({key: .[0], value: .[1]}) | from_entries'
```

It seems easier to follow to me as well, although it is quite long too; I assume, however, that the focus is readability and not character count. Of course, you can also mix up both solutions:

```
jq '[.key, .string] | transpose | map({(.[0]): .[1]}) | add'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which uses **reduce** with a state object holding an iteration index and a result object.  It iterates over `.key` setting corresponding values in the result from `.string`

```
  .string as $v
| reduce .key[] as $k (
   {idx:0, result:{}}; .result[$k] = $v[.idx] | .idx += 1
  )
| .result
```